# High I/O load when hosting lots of wordpress sites

Tags: performance, server

I have a vps that hosts about 30 separate wordpress sites and I notice it that does a lot disk writes. In total it does 5mb/sec disk write. Is there anyway to decrease the disk write? cause each time I add more wordpress site it increases

Comment: What, specifically, are the disk writes? That could be any number of things. I am afraid this is probably too broad as I am pretty sure it will take hands on server level debugging to figure out.

Comment: I have a WP multisite installation with over 200 sites for an enterprise.  We do not have any disk i/o issues. WP doesnt really write to disk, the httpd server does.  Have you checked to see if any plugins you use are writing to disk?

Comment: well the only plugin that could be writing is W3 Total Cache + APC